# Jquery, an autoscroll to bottom function at a constant speed

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to develop an autoscroll to bottom function that goes at a constant speed and in a smooth way independently from the height of the document and that allows ajax content loading.

here is my attempt

```
$bottom = 100;
function scroll() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$bottom}, 2000, 'linear');
        $bottom = $bottom + 100;
        scroll();
}

scroll();
```

any suggestion to improve it a bit? I'm not happy with the smoothness.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain or show us with a live example what exactly the problem is with the "smoothness"

Comment: You could try setting `scrollTop` to `$(document).height()`. Then you don't need to bother with the `$bottom = $bottom + 100;` or re-calling the `scroll()` function from inside the function. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/GjWBh/